# Joint PDF of all n Order Statistics

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a random sample from a continuous distribution with pdf $f_{\theta}(x)$, why is the joint PDF of the order statistics $X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)}$ the following: $$\large f_{X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)}}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=n!\prod_{i=1}^nf_{\theta}(x_i)$$

I'm not sure where the $n!$ is coming from. Is the joint PDF of all $n$ order statistics not just a "re-ordering" of the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$? And the joint distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is just $\large\prod\limits_{i=1}^n f_{\theta}(x_i)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/795949/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2763082/321264

Answer (score 4):

$$
f_{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)
=
\prod_{i=1}^nf_{\theta}(x_i)
$$
$$
f_{X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)}}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)
=
n!\cdot\prod_{i=1}^nf_{\theta}(x_i)\cdot\mathbf 1_{x_1\lt x_2\lt\cdots\lt x_n}
$$